# MongooseError [MongooseServerSelectionError]: connection <monitor> to 52.6.250.237:27017 closed

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to save data in mongodb through post method and using mongodb atlas with node.js but it keeps giving me an error, I provided correct connection string and correct password. Please help in regarding this issue. Thanks.

Here is the code:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const monngodb_url="mongodb+srv://maarij:asdf360@cluster0-j7wis.mongodb.net/authDB?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

mongoose.connect(monngodb_url, {useNewUrlParser: true,useUnifiedTopology: true}).then(()=>{
    console.log("mongodb is connected");
}).catch((error)=>{
    console.log("mondb not connected");
    console.log(error);
});
```

Here is the error:

```
server is running on port 3000
{ name: 'myName', email: 'e@mail.com', password: 'abcdefg' }
mondb not connected
MongooseError [MongooseServerSelectionError]: connection <monitor> to 52.6.250.237:27017 closed
    at new MongooseServerSelectionError (D:\react-native\reactNativeBackend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\serverSelection.js:22:11)
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (D:\react-native\reactNativeBackend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:808:32)
    at Mongoose.connect (D:\react-native\reactNativeBackend\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:333:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\react-native\reactNativeBackend\db\db.js:5:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:955:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:848:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\react-native\reactNativeBackend\index.js:4:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:955:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1043:10) {
  message: 'connection <monitor> to 52.6.250.237:27017 closed',
  name: 'MongooseServerSelectionError',
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
    setName: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    servers: Map {
      'cluster0-shard-00-01-j7wis.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'cluster0-shard-00-02-j7wis.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'cluster0-shard-00-00-j7wis.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription]
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    compatibilityError: null,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    commonWireVersion: null
  },
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
}
```

Comment: You might want to delete this question and ask it again with login credentials and url removed.

Comment: That's so clearly a fake password, people. Look at your keyboard, starting at 'A'. The error message echo is the full row while the `monngodb_url` line above it uses a different variant starting with the same 4 not-so-random characters. Last but not least, the hostname `cluster0-j7wis.mongodb.net` doesn't exist.

Comment: @double-beep: you missed the line where the actual password would go, the `monngodb_url` value.

Comment: I'll add this for future searchers. If you are setting up a Cluster and Database through the Mongo Atlas DB website AND you're using a Mac and Safari, check if "Private Relay" is on. If so, your IP Address will change periodically. This may cause your connections to fail.

Answer (score 199):

**You Can Solve This Problem By Going into Your Network Access Panel**

[image: Network Panel]

**Then Click Add IP Address**

[image: Add Ip Address]

**& Then Fill 0.0.0.0/0 Then Click Confirm**

> Don't Do this in Production But in Development, it will Work

Comment: Not sure if its the best solution but its quick adn worked for me! thanks

Comment: Hey Avi,  This is the quick solution for Development Purpose only this is just to remind you that please remove this when you are in development or take another server for prod and don't add this on production one. Add only IP Addresses of your server

Comment: For me, I had twice to delete / add `allow all` and still it didn't work till I included `my-curent-ip` and `allow all` - after I deleted `my-curent-ip` and the `allow all` worked.... something with Mongo Atlas...

Comment: You can (and should) use your current IP address instead of `0.0.0.0/0`. It is not unique to just your device, but it's far more unique than allowing all IPs.

Comment: @enkicoma i agree with you..It started to work after i add both the allow all and my-current-ip..then i have deleted my-current-ip

Comment: If you use Netlify Functions, you need to use this even on the production website, as Netlify has dosens of IPs. More about it here: https://dev.to/_phzn/accessing-mongodb-atlas-from-netlify-functions-1h70

Answer (score 28):

I had the same issue but I success to fix it.
On your MongoDB account, check the IP you choose to connect your application.

If you start working on a initial IP and try to work using another IP address it won't work.

In mongoDB:

NetworkAccess/ (verify the IP you registered is the same than this your actually used). You can select : Add IP address

Comment: Thanks. This saved my 2.5 hours useless effort. You have to actually white list your IP.

Answer (score 20):

I had this similar problem.
'Go to network access' -> 'IP whitelist' -> you can only connect to your cluster from those IP addresses , so if your IP is not present in that list

Then Click the 'Add IP address' Button-> in there click the button 'Add your current IP address'.

Comment: This should be the correct answer, the top answer is not safe ‍♂️

Answer (score 10):

This is probably because the IP of your machine changes, it should not happen in production, but to fix it you need to go to the network access pannel -> Add IP Address and click on "Add this IP address" and it´s going to work, until it changes again.

Comment: This was my issue, using next-auth to connect to mongodb

Answer (score 9):

The main problem here is with `Mongodb Atlas`.  The method that worked for
me was to delete the existing IP address in network section of Mongodb
Atlas, and add it again.

Answer (score 3):

it does not allow to connect because of your ip. to solve this issue just open  your project in **cloud.mongodb** in left side open **NetworkAccess**

**only pc`s can access to your project listed here**
[image]

**Click add Ip Address**
then fill 0.0.0.0/0

[image]

**lastly you will see**
[image]

and now it is worked

Comment: Thanks . it worked for me. added 0.0.0.0/0 as allowed IP address list and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

I re logged-in to Atlas (https://cloud.mongodb.com/). and it showed me a warning message that my IP address is not added. I have added this and it started working.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Did you have this line in your index.js `app.use(cors())`?

Try to delete this line and delete everything that involves cors.

If this don't work try the Mehdi Berra's solution

Answer (score 1):

The most voted solution won't work in most cases. You should first follow the steps of "Aka"'s solution and then remove your `node_modules` folder. After that, just run `npm i` to re-install all the dependencies and you should be good to go, considering you have the dependencies registered in the `package.json`

Comment: It didn't work for me.  Who is 'Aka' and where is his/her solution?

Answer (score 1):

I think if you delete or add a new IP address in network Access tab of your mongodb your Project will not run successfully until you will not refresh server main file(index.js).
Because many times I added a new IP address it doesn't work until I refresh index.js

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can also solve by going to `Network Access > Edit > ADD CURRENT IP ADDRESS`

Answer (score 0):

### double check the connection config vars in Heroku

Hi OP and everyone,

When I landed on this page, I found I had already whitelisted my ip, so that was already solved, but my page was still not connecting to atlas, so I troubleshooted.

If you're having trouble, make sure your config vars has the same key as is in your connection in your code, for instance MONGODB_URI

I had my key different between heroku and my code in one deployment, and it took me a long time to figure out.

Then this time I had my value wrong. After I confirmed my IP address was whitelisted, I looked into the value of the MONGODB_URI, in my current case I didn't have the database AND COLLECTION as part of the value. In Mongodb Atlas when you click connect to the cluster to get the connection string, it will tell you ... mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase ... and to replace the myFirstDataBase with your database name. *Mine also needed to include the collection.* For instance, mine was this, `mongodb.net/booksearch_db` missing the collection which made it work seen here `mongodb.net/booksearch_db_booksearch`

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was the wi-fi network I was connected to because when I used my mobile net through hotspot the error was gone.