# Connection error between nodejs and mongodb atlas using mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

I am trying to build a backend app using mongodb atlas. I have followed the instruction but I got error like this

```
{ MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 18.140.224.177:27017
at new MongooseServerSelectionError 
...
  message: 'connect ECONNREFUSED 18.140.224.177:27017',
  name: 'MongooseServerSelectionError',
  reason:
   TopologyDescription {
     type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
     setName: null,
     maxSetVersion: null,
     maxElectionId: null,
     servers:
      Map {
        'database-shard-00-01-ayo9w.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
        'database-shard-00-00-ayo9w.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
        'database-shard-00-02-ayo9w.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription] 
     stale: false,
     compatible: true,
     compatibilityError: null,
     logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
     heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
     localThresholdMS: 15,
     commonWireVersion: null },
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
```

and here is my code

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://thanh:Abcdefghijk@database-ayo9w.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority",
    { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, },
  ).then(() => console.log('Connected to database')).
  catch(err => console.log('Error in connection', err));
```

My whitelist entry in mongodb atlas is 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60563988/unhandledpromiserejectionwarning-mongooseserverselectionerror/60584076#60584076.  You can have a look .. And add your username and password.

Comment: I have tried it also but it's still the same issue

Comment: Did you add username and password ??

Comment: try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60431996/mongooseerror-mongooseserverselectionerror-connection-monitor-to-52-6-250-2

Comment: Yes I have added my username and password. That is the one in Database Access right?

Comment: Doesn't it works after adding `username` and `password`?

Comment: It's still not working

Answer (score 0):

Change username and password with your database username and password. Check mongoDB Atlas where you have created your database and collections.

Comment: username and password is the one in Database access -> Database user right?

Comment: Yes,  and whitelist your IP.

Comment: Is is possible that I put it 0.0.0.0/0? I have tried Add current IP address option but it doesn't work

Comment: Follow this video after 50 seconds and you are good to go https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sOUNgOx0GcU&list=PL55RiY5tL51rG1x02Yyj93iypUuHYXcB_&index=5

Comment: I think what I did is similar to this video, but it's still not working

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is the internet connection. I just change my wifi connection and it works. This is the link where I get the answer

[Error at connecting to MongoDb Atlas Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49894913/error-at-connecting-to-mongodb-atlas-server/55665459)

Answer (score 0):

Your network or hosting has port 27017 blocked, that's why you can't access server.

- To test if the port is blocked you can try this on terminal on mac/linux
  (curl portquiz.net:27017) or on cmd (nc -v portquiz.net 27017)

This should solve your issue.