# Why am I seeing "Application Error" after deploying my nodejs application to heroku and connected with mongob atlas?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

MongoDB connection file

```
module.exports={
database:process.env.MONGODB_URI || "mongodb://localhost:27017/blogdb",
secret:"secretkey"
};
```

MongoDB connection code

```
mongoose.connect(config.database, {useNewUrlParser: true,useUnifiedTopology: true});
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function() {
   console.log('Connected to mongodb');
});
```

whitelisted Ip's-
0.0.0.0/0  (includes your current IP address)

Heroku logs are attached as screenshots[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you scroll a bit up and post a picture of the start of the stack trace?

Comment: updated my question

Comment: This post seems to be related, have you gone through the possible solutions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60431996/mongooseerror-mongooseserverselectionerror-connection-monitor-to-52-6-250-2

Comment: whitelisted Ip's- 0.0.0.0/0 (includes your current IP address)   I have done that already

Comment: Atlas requires TLS/SSL, do you have that specified in your connection string?

Comment: Can you at least do a .catch() so we can see what exactly is the error?