# How to resolve "unspecified name" error of postman when running URL of Heroku | NodeJs | MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, flutter, heroku, postman

I am new to Heroku, NodeJS and MongoDB. I created a login form in flutter and its backend is in NodeJS and MongoDB. I used Heroku for connecting backend to flutter, but when I run the URL (which is given by Heroku at the time of building project) on postman it gives me "unspecified name"

here is code of my app.js

```
var body = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
var mongodb = require('mongodb')
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/Mongodb'
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(body.json());
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js")
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const router= express.Router()
const User = require('./connection');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/Mongodb', { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true },function(err){
  if(err){
    console.log(err)
  }else{
    console.log("connection Successful")
  }
})


// router.get('/Dashboard', (req, res) => {
//   res.send('Hello World')
// })

function checkToken(req,res,result){
  const header= req.headers.token;
  if(typeof header !== 'undefined'){
    const bearer =header.split('.');
    const token = bearer[1]
    //console.log(token)
    req.token = token 
    //next();
    result();
  }else
  res.json("Error")
  }  

const login = require('./routes/login')
app.post("/login", async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log("login api hit")
  login(req,res,next)
  } )  

const userDashboard = require('./routes/userdashboard')
app.post("/Dashboard",checkToken,(req,res)=>  {
  userDashboard(req,res);
}) 

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000
  app.listen(PORT, function(){
 
    console.log("Server is running")
    
  })
```

here is the code for **./routes/login**

```
var body = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
var mongodb = require('mongodb')
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/Mongodb'
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(body.json());
const User = require('../connection');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js")
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

login=(req,res,next)=>{  
  console.log(req.data)
  User.find({"username":req.body.username},function(err,data){
    if(err){
      console.log("unspecified name")
      res.status(400).json("unspecified name")
      return;
    } 
    else{
    console.log(data.length)
         if(data.length<=0)
      {
        res.status(300).json({
          "message":"Invalid Input!"
        })  
      }
      else {
           
        //bcrypt.compare(req.body.password,data[0].password).then(function(result) {
          var bytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(data[0].password, 'my-secret-key@123');
          var decryptedData = JSON.parse(bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
          console.log(decryptedData)
            if (req.body.password==decryptedData)
              {
                login = "Succesful";            
                var token = jwt.sign({
                  data: 'foobar'
           }, 'secret', { expiresIn: "2 minute"})
           res.status(200).json({auth: true,  AccessToken:token,  User:data[0]}) 
          }
           else
           {res.status(300).json({
            "message":"Input!"
          })}
          
          //  });
          
        }}
      })
}
module.exports = login;
```

here is the snap which shows **"login api hit"**

[image]

here is the snap which shows **"Server is running"**

[image]

and here is the **404 error** annd **400 error**

[image]

and here is the **postman** snap

[image]

Now let me know please is my server is running properly? it seems it is! but why it's showing **"unspecified name"** on postman?
kindly please help I'm new in this stuff, any help will be appreciated!

Thank you!

**---------------------------EDITED POST---------------------------------------**

my database data is look like this

[image]

but cmd screen shows this
[image]

can anyone tell me what is logic behind this? from where these came?

**------------------------EDITED POST---------------------------------------------**

This is the output when I enter the credentials!

[image]

and here it is ouput of cmd

```
2021-05-25T11:04:30.507933+00:00 app[web.1]: Server is running
2021-05-25T11:04:30.682233+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-05-25T11:05:00.561298+00:00 app[web.1]: MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/
2021-05-25T11:05:00.561320+00:00 app[web.1]: at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:832:32)
2021-05-25T11:05:00.561321+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:345:10
2021-05-25T11:05:00.561335+00:00 app[web.1]: at promiseOrCallback (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:9:12)
2021-05-25T11:05:00.561341+00:00 app[web.1]: at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:1135:10)
2021-05-25T11:05:00.561342+00:00 app[web.1]: at Mongoose.connect (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:344:20)
2021-05-25T11:05:00.561343+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/app.js:13:10)
2021-05-25T11:05:00.561343+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1068:30)
2021-05-25T11:05:00.561344+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
2021-05-25T11:05:00.561344+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)
2021-05-25T11:05:00.561344+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)
2021-05-25T11:05:00.561345+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
2021-05-25T11:05:00.561345+00:00 app[web.1]: at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
2021-05-25T11:05:00.561346+00:00 app[web.1]: reason: TopologyDescription {
2021-05-25T11:05:00.561346+00:00 app[web.1]: type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
2021-05-25T11:05:00.561346+00:00 app[web.1]: setName: null,
2021-05-25T11:05:00.561347+00:00 app[web.1]: maxSetVersion: null,
2021-05-25T11:05:00.561347+00:00 app[web.1]: maxElectionId: null,
2021-05-25T11:05:00.561348+00:00 app[web.1]: servers: Map(3) {
2021-05-25T11:05:00.561348+00:00 app[web.1]: 'cluster0-shard-00-02.ocarv.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
2021-05-25T11:05:00.561348+00:00 app[web.1]: 'cluster0-shard-00-00.ocarv.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
2021-05-25T11:05:00.561349+00:00 app[web.1]: 'cluster0-shard-00-01.ocarv.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription]
2021-05-25T11:05:00.561350+00:00 app[web.1]: },
2021-05-25T11:05:00.561350+00:00 app[web.1]: stale: false,
2021-05-25T11:05:00.561350+00:00 app[web.1]: compatible: true,
2021-05-25T11:05:00.561350+00:00 app[web.1]: compatibilityError: null,
2021-05-25T11:05:00.561351+00:00 app[web.1]: logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
2021-05-25T11:05:00.561351+00:00 app[web.1]: heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
2021-05-25T11:05:00.561351+00:00 app[web.1]: localThresholdMS: 15,
2021-05-25T11:05:00.561352+00:00 app[web.1]: commonWireVersion: null
2021-05-25T11:05:00.561352+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2021-05-25T11:05:00.561352+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2021-05-25T11:15:57.214740+00:00 app[web.1]: login api hit
2021-05-25T11:15:57.215001+00:00 app[web.1]: {}
2021-05-25T11:16:07.230564+00:00 app[web.1]: unspecified name
2021-05-25T11:16:07.247306+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:19
2021-05-25T11:16:07.247307+00:00 app[web.1]: throw error;
2021-05-25T11:16:07.247308+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2021-05-25T11:16:07.247308+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-05-25T11:16:07.247309+00:00 app[web.1]: ReferenceError: print is not defined
2021-05-25T11:16:07.247310+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/routes/login.js:19:7
2021-05-25T11:16:07.247310+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4863:16
2021-05-25T11:16:07.247310+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4863:16
2021-05-25T11:16:07.247311+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:16:11
2021-05-25T11:16:07.247311+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4886:21
2021-05-25T11:16:07.247312+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4389:18
2021-05-25T11:16:07.247312+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:4424:14
2021-05-25T11:16:07.247313+00:00 app[web.1]: at cb (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1895:14)
2021-05-25T11:16:07.247313+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/mquery/lib/collection/node.js:27:21
2021-05-25T11:16:07.247314+00:00 app[web.1]: at collectionOperationCallback (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js:160:26)
2021-05-25T11:16:07.247323+00:00 app[web.1]: at Timeout.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js:185:11)
2021-05-25T11:16:07.247323+00:00 app[web.1]: at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:555:17)
2021-05-25T11:16:07.247324+00:00 app[web.1]: at processTimers (internal/timers.js:498:7)
2021-05-25T11:16:07.247324+00:00 app[web.1]: Emitted 'error' event on Function instance at:
2021-05-25T11:16:07.247324+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:4865:13
2021-05-25T11:16:07.247325+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:16:11
2021-05-25T11:16:07.247325+00:00 app[web.1]: [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
2021-05-25T11:16:07.247326+00:00 app[web.1]: at processTimers (internal/timers.js:498:7)
2021-05-25T11:16:07.314225+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-05-25T11:16:07.401592+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2021-05-25T11:16:07.409072+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-05-25T11:16:07.240945+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/login" host=attendance-demo.herokuapp.com request_id=ac9410a0-ac64-420b-b4d5-803aaa1a3fb2 fwd="111.88.134.32" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=10035ms status=400 bytes=234 protocol=https
2021-05-25T11:16:18.897092+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app`
2021-05-25T11:16:30.471917+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-05-25T11:16:30.423428+00:00 app[web.1]: Server is running
```

and here is the **authenticate.dart** file which i called on button click

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
class AuthService{
  Dio dio=new Dio();

  login(name,password)async{
    try{
      return await dio.post('https://attendance-demo.herokuapp.com/login',data: {
        "username":name,
        "password":password
      },options: Options(contentType:Headers.formUrlEncodedContentType)
      );
    }
    on DioError catch(e){
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: e.response.data['msg'],
      toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
      gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      textColor: Colors.white,
      fontSize: 16.0
      );
    }

  }
}
```

and here is the **code of login button i created** and calling login method from authentication class

```
  RoundedButton(text:"Login",  press: () {
                     AuthService().login(name,password).then((value){
                       if(value.data['success']){
                         token=value.data['token'];
                         Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Authenticated',
                         toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                        gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                        textColor: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 16.0);
                         
                       }
```

Comment: Where is the `login` function defined?

Comment: in the app.js file, "app.post("/login", async (req, res, next) => { " check this line

Comment: Where is this code `require('./routes/login')`? The error could be there. You are calling the `login()` function, but have not posted the code there.

Comment: @RaulSauco I edit my post, posted login() code, please check it now.

Comment: In login function, try to console req.body instead of req.data. Connection fn looks fishy, please share the code.

Comment: which code u want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your mongodb Client is running on your local machine you must make a cloud base mongodb cluster like [Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas) and change your mongo URI with cloud base cluster URI.

Comment: yess ali you're right! i did that, but i want to ask one thing, can u please give me answer about this

Comment: i think you console log your entered credentials not the data came from db as the below line after that console "unspecified user" is log i think this is log after db query.

Comment: So what I have to do now ali? i edit my post again please check it, when i enter the credentials this came up!

Comment: your username and password is "munib" as stored in db and your try with "munib123" as password.

Comment: Ali please check it now i edit the post, check the output of cmd and i enter Munib on both username and password

Comment: now it is displaying "unspecified name" after login hit

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

So, after spending lots of hours, I finally got solution! problem was my Mongodb was connected, issue was IP address so thanks to stackoverflow team I got solution from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60431996/mongooseerror-mongooseserverselectionerror-connection-monitor-to-52-6-250-2) (Aka's solution) now I'm connected to my database!