# MongoServerSelectionError: connection <monitor> to <MyIP> closed

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, mongo-shell

I have started learning MongoDB, I am just trying to connect to the database using MongoDB Shell.
I am using the below command.

```
mongosh "mongodb+srv://cluster0.12345.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase" --username viveknuna
```

I have added my current IP Address to IP Access List. But getting this error.

> MongoServerSelectionError: connection  to  closed

I have referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60431996/6527049) question and added 0.0.0.0/0 (Allow access from AnyWhere) in the IP Access List. and it works as expected. But this is a security risk, Is there any way without allowing all IPs.

**FYI**: I am inside Virtual Machine and running this command also from VM.

Comment: "my current IP" should be your public IP, the one you see in https://checkip.amazonaws.com/. E.g. `curl https://checkip.amazonaws.com/` from within your VM

Comment: @AlexBlex yes it is public ip, which is the same I am getting on accessing https://checkip.amazonaws.com/

Comment: Can you telnet to one of the nodes? `dig srv _mongodb._tcp.cluster0.12345.mongodb.net +short` to get urls of the nodes, then `telnet` to one of them on the port from the response.

Comment: I am getting the error 'dig' is not recognized as an internal or external command when running this command `dig srv _mongodb._tcp.cluster0.12345.mongodb.net +short`. FYI I am working on a windows machine @AlexBlex

Comment: Is windows guest or host or both?  Anyway, there plenty online services to read DNS records. I believe mxtoolbox has SRV lookup. You will need telnet on your machine to test connectivity tho. Are you using any proxies or VPN?

Comment: I’m not using any proxy or vpn, but I’m using virtual machine @AlexBlex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in my case when i got these error `MongoServerSelectionError: connection <monitor> to 16.163.195.9:27017 closed`

I actualy put the wrong ip address i put my private ip; thats why.

i fixed it by changing the ip address in the IP List from WAN IP to my Public IP address thats how i fixed it, just search what is my ip, in you favorite seach Engine and it will show you your public ip in the result.

Answer (score 1):

For me this error was occurring because my connection string was wrong.To be very specific - I copied the sample connection string from a course I was learning and just replaced the username and password with my credentials. So, the credentials were right but not the rest of the connection string.

Just for the sake of understanding. Please see below :

```
 mongodb+srv://myusername:mypassword@courseproject.h1mpg.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
```

**myusername** and **mypassword** are correct i.e belongs to my cluster in MongoDB atlas account, but the rest of the string is wrong as I copied it from somewhere instead of copying it from my own MongoDB atlas account.

So please make sure to double check if your entire connection string is correct.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when your ip address on the remote mongoDb is not the same as the public ip address of your computer. Simply go to network access on atlas and add your public ip address. Also, if your ip address is the same as that on the remote mongoDb then probably the connection closed after some period(default is 6hours).Thus when adding a your ip, unsure you toggle and set the duration for the connection (max is a week)