# Cant connect to mongoDB atlas even if my IP is whitelisted

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, nosql, ip

MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/security-whitelist/
at _handleConnectionErrors (C:\Users\Gigabyte\Desktop\3rdYear2ndSem\SoftEng\BatstateU-tenants\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:755:11)
at NativeConnection.openUri (C:\Users\Gigabyte\Desktop\3rdYear2ndSem\SoftEng\BatstateU-tenants\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:730:11)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

```
{
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
servers: Map(3) {
      'ac-btvwsde-shard-00-00.vktogmw.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'ac-btvwsde-shard-00-01.vktogmw.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'ac-btvwsde-shard-00-02.vktogmw.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription]
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: 'atlas-ze47mp-shard-0',
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined
}
```

I did whitelist my public IP address provided by https://www.whatismyip.com/, however, I still get the error when I try to run my server

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60431996/mongooseerror-mongooseserverselectionerror-connection-monitor-to-52-6-250-2 Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, to solve the problem just use a VPN and whitelist the public IP address you got. This issue might be because of my ISP.